# Hide website service path and its php files from viewing

Tags: php, .htaccess, path, host

I did a lot of research but I still can't find a solution to my problem. There is a site that for some reason can easily show his content if you access paths like this:

domain.com/templates/orange/forums/sections/forum_item.php

I don't know how to hide all /template directory from viewing.
The site is very odd, normally all modern systems have the feature I need in default configuration, but this one doesn't.
I tried to do a .htaccess redirect for /template, but obviously website design have stopped working
Please advise.

Comment: you place your code higher document root and use single entry point for your app

Comment: Do you want to restrict access to `/templates` URI?

Comment: So do you want to keep this URL `domain.com/orange/forums/sections/forum_item.php`? (just took out `/template/`)

Answer (score 0):

I like to put any code I don't want directly accessing out of the `document root` and sub-directories. For instance if you have this setup:

```
index.php
|_templates/
  |_home.php
  |_about.php
  |_contact.php
|_models/
  |_home.php
  |_about.php
  |_contact.php
```

I would instead have this:

```
|_public_html
  |_index.php
|_templates/
  |_home.php
  |_about.php
  |_contact.php
|_models/
  |_home.php
  |_about.php
  |_contact.php
```

In this case, the apache config's document root wouldn't need to be changed, but you would need to change the include paths. So, from index.php you might do something like:

```
<?php
include '../models/about.php';
include ../templates/about.php
```